# How to add marker in Google maps from another class using button in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, button, marker

I have a problem I don't know what is the cause of error. I have two class namely Map2.java and CameraVertical.java
In Map2.java I have a method on button that pass a coordinates separately LAT and LNG so this is the code of Map2.java:

```
public void passData(){
   btnSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intentCover = new Intent(Map2.this,CameraVertical.class);
          intentCover.putExtra("lat",lat);
          intentCover.putExtra("lng",lng);
          startActivity(intentCover);
          finish();
        }
    });
}
```

I receive the coordinates(lat / lng) in my CameraVertical.java display it using text view and this is the code:

```
Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
double lat2 = extra.getDouble("lat");
double lng2 = extra.getDouble("lng");
final LatLng latlng = new LatLng(lat2,lng2);
txtLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLatitude);
txtLocation.setText(latlng.latitude + latlng.longitude);
```

The coordinates I receive from Map2.java is successfully displayed. But when I add a new marker from that coordinates(the one displayed) I create an object from Map2 namely maps so that I can access my map to add marker. I get the error and this is the code:

```
btnNext.setOnclickListener(new View.OnclickListener(){
@Override
 public void onClick(View v){
  Map2 maps = new Map2();
  maps.mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng));
  maps.mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(low));
  maps.mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17.0f));
  Intent intentMap = new Intent(CameraVertical.this, Map2.class);
  startActivity(intentMap);
  finish();
 }
};
```

Please help me! The marker didn't add in the map using that coordinates(the one I received).

Comment: As per the code you are traversing from Map2 to CameraVertical and back to Map2. You may pass the new value along with the intent and not by creating the Map2 Object.  Whats the error you are getting

Comment: The error I get is on the adding of marker from that coordinates

Comment: Can you give an example on adding a marker using a button? from another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if your `mGoogleMap` is ready, so that a marker can be added.

Comment: My Google map is working because I passed a coordinates to another class.